# Alamofire JSON Parsing fails when parse non multidimensional JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hi I'm new to Alamofire JSON parsing, I had no problem to parse these data

```
[  
   "main":{  
      "country":"Indonesia",
      "city":"Jakarta",
      "location":"Field",
      "latitude":"6.1745",
      "longitude":"106.8227"
   }
]
```

but im unable to parse these

```
[  
   {  
      "country":"Indonesia",
      "city":"Jakarta",
      "location":"Field",
      "latitude":"6.1745",
      "longitude":"106.8227"
   }
]
```

even though i modified my code. I need to use the second JSON data which is not working, because my website automatically generates that data. Here's my code : JSONStandart is Dictionary< String, AnyObject >

```
func downloadData(completed: @escaping ()-> ()) {

    let reqURL = URL(string: url!)
    Alamofire.request(reqURL!).responseJSON {
        response in

        if let error = response.result.error {
            print(error)
        }


        if let dict = response.result.value as? JSONStandart , let country = dict["country"] as? String, let city = dict["city"] as? String, let location = dict["location"] as? String, let latitude = dict["latitude"] as? Double, let longitude = dict["longitude"] as? Double {

            self._country = country
            self._city = city
            self._location = location
            self._latitude = latitude
            self._longitude = longitude
        }
        completed()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your 1st JSON isn't valid. Your 2nd JSON is an array of dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm also able to extract my 2nd using the usual JSON parsing without Alamofire, but this time i want to use Alamofire

Comment: But the code you posted is treating the JSON as a dictionary. It's not a dictionary. It's and array containing a dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy i change my format to dictionary array and it worked! Thanks a lot!